# batch Fraction to %

Tags: batch-file, variables, math

I have been trying to write a short script in the batch that converts two variables in fraction format (%a%, the numerator, and %b%, the denominator) to a percentage (%c%)

batch variables only support integers, so I cant use:

```
set /A c="%a% / %b% * 100"
```

I have heard of workarounds for this via .vbs scripts (export %a% and %b% to a script, have the script do the maths, and import the result back to batch)

is there a simpler way to do this? particularly without using an external script (if it has to be an external script it should be temporarily created in the same directory as the .bat then deleted after its purpose is fulfilled)

I am sure this sounds like a "do it for me" type question but I cant find the answer anywhere, if theres a simpler way to do it, please help me out.

Comment: `set /A` does 32-bit signed integer arithmetics…

Comment: @aschipfl alright, I'm aware of that, 'set /A' does not support the use of real numbers (decimals) so the expression I put up would not work due to the fact that the first operation (/) spits out a decimal which is always rounded down, meaning that unless the result of the operation is 1, it will always come out 0. thus C can only be 0 or 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the integer values you can reorder the expression

```
set /A "c= (a*100) / b"
```

For a bit more accuracy you could use

```
set /A "c= ( a*100 + b/2 ) / b"
```

And if you need some decimal places, just multiply with a bigger value

```
set /A "r= (a*10000) / b"
echo %r:~0,-2%.%r:~-2%
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing math with decimals is one of the very few times I will recommend using powershell in a batch script.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('powershell %a%/%b%*100') do set "c=%%A"
```

Comment: sadly, I may not be able to use PowerShell, i'm writing this script on an old air-gapped machine running windows XP pro, (its a long story), PowerShell doesn't come pre-installed until windows 7.

Comment: No need to explain; I've seen plenty of applications in production environments that weren't compatible with Windows after XP.